# Calling .bat from a Windows service

Tags: c#, windows, service

I'm developing a Windows service with c#, that has to call a .bat which generates some pdf's so my service can send them by email to some users.

I've been stuck in this problem for some days now, so I tried to do something simpler like make my service execute chrome.exe. In both cases, my service can call the .exe/.bat but I can't see them or they don't do anything. Here's an example:

I have 9 Google Chrome running, but I can't see them, I'm currently with just one windows with one tab typing this question
[image: I have 9 Google Chrome running, but I can't see them, I'm currently with just one window with one tab typing this question.]

What it could be?

Comment: "Can't see them" as in "the application window does not become visible"? If this is the case, windows service does not interact with the UI.

Comment: Yeah, but when i tell my service to execute chrome.exe, shouldn't a google chrome windows pop up in my screen?

Comment: No. The Chrome window will not pop up. Windows service is specifically designed to run without interaction with the UI.

Comment: As @Barns stated windows services run in the background. You'll need to use unmanaged extern calls to interactive with whatever it is you're trying to call. What is the reason for starting Chrome? What does the batch script do?

Comment: @garty my main goal it's to execute a .bat who generates pdf's from my windows service, but it seems to be more complex. So to begin to understand windows services, processes, windows sessions, etc...i created a windows service who called chrome, just to learn.

Comment: @Estudeiro We've had the same problem here, the old team were using Word to generate the pdfs which requires running in the foreground, so we couldn't move it over to a windows service. How do you generate PDFs? If you require foreground then use a scheduled task or another task runner.

Comment: @garty thank you, we used windows task manager, and it seems to run now. But still, i'm not satisfied with the solution haha.

Comment: You should learn what's session isolation https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/application-compatibility-session-0-isolation/ba-p/372361 and then see why UI displayed by a session 0 application (like your Windows service) and its child processes (Chrome) are not visible to the logon user.